# What's an adjective for excessively hand gesturing while talking?

Tags: word-request

Suppose you are being interviewed for a job, and while you're making a presentation, you find yourself (in a fit) excessively hand gesturing to the obvious inconvenience of the interviewer. Now you would like to apologize for that:

> I'm sorry for making too much gestures.
>
> I'm sorry for being excessive with my hands.

Are the above OK? Is there a one-word adjective that can capture the meaning?

Comment: I would probably use a verb rather than an adjective; something like "I'm so sorry, I tend to **flail about** when I get nervous." But in the US, I'd only apologize for this if I actually managed to knock something over or make someone dizzy or a similar really obvious effect.

Answer (score 9):

I think the word you want is gesticulations.

So you could say either "Sorry for all the gesticulations" or "I'm sorry about my gesticulating."

Comment: This word fits to a T, but I'm not convinced it's the word the O.P. "wants". (Learners ought to know that this could be regarded as a "50-cent word", meaning it's not all that commonly used.)

Comment: I’d also suggest that this is a word that warrants some guidance as to its pronunciation, since it is not particularly intuitive (*jest-ick-you-lay-shuns* perhaps, using simpler English words).

Comment: "ubergesticulational" :)

Comment: @J.R. Dollar value ranges from $0.50 on to upwards of $2 or even $3 seem par for the course here at ell.

Comment: @KRyan I think the pronunciation begins with _jes-tick-_. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gesticulate

Comment: @user151841 Yeah, that's closer, but *jes* isn't an English word and the *j* sound on the front of the word is the one that strikes me as most surprising so I wanted something directly comparable there.

Comment: @KRyan would you accept "Jess", a common nickname for a Jessica or Jesse?

Comment: @user151841 Ah, yeah, that's a good suggestion.

Comment: @Chowzen I prefer "gesticular" :)

Comment: I concur; I prefer something like "I apologize for my excessive amount of gesticulation."

Comment: @iRove - Really? _I apologize for my excessive amount of gesticulation?_ At a job interview? I don't think it would make the O.P. a frontrunner. I think something like Lawrence's solution would sound more "normal": _I'm sorry if I'm moving my hands too much._

Comment: @user151841 - In single-word-request questions, yes. I think many of these are interesting words to consider and learn, and there's a time and place for them. However, I think we owe it to the learner to at least give them a clue if a suggested word is going to be immediately understood, or might raise some _what-in-the-world-are-you-talking-about_ eyebrows instead.

Comment: @talrnu I don't think the OP would consider, "I apologize for moving my hands so much; I have gesticular cancer."

Comment: @J.R. I guess so...it doesn't sound _that_ unnatural to me but unnatural nonetheless.  You are right that it probably wouldn't be a good idea to use this in a job interview; it sounds like you might even be trying to impress the interviewer with your extensive vocabulary!

Comment: @iRove - If we're talking about a journalist writing a review of a political speech, TED talk, or standup comedy routine, then _gesticulating_ or _gesticulation_ could be an ideal word. But it just seems a bit much in that apology.

Comment: I think it is a pretty common word, I would be surprised if I met anybody who didn't know it.

Answer (score 8):

I'd probably say something like the following:

> "I'm sorry for being so animated"

[**Animated**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animated) in this case being used to describe something *full of movement and activity* or *very expressive*.

It's commonly used for people who are very energetic with their movements and expressions. However, in my experience it can also carry a sense of enthusiasm, so if you're using your hands a lot but you're delivering a eulogy, this choice may not be appropriate :^)

**That said**: As was suggested, "I'm sorry for talking with my hands so much" is also perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It should be noted that you can be an "animated" talker/speaker without any hand gestures, e.g. if your face is highly expressive or your whole body moves energetically. If you're trying to convey the specific idea of hand movements, use of this word requires additional clarification.

Comment: That's a good point Talrnu

Comment: @talrnu - True, but in the situation described in the question – where the speaker is already in the process having very animated hands – that can be easily discerned.

Answer (score 1):

[*Gesticular*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gesticular)

> characterized or accompanied by gesticulation

This fits pretty well, you're just a gesticular person.

Answer (score 0):

A way you could express your apology is to say "sorry for waving my hands so much"

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your answer. Your answer would be more useful if you explained why you believe this would be an appropriate response. Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will answer more questions and ask some of your own!

Answer (score 0):

I believe fidgeting may be used here:

```
fidget

make small movements, especially of the hands and feet, through nervousness or impatience.
```

Comment: Someone who's talking with their hands typically isn't making *small* movements.